# Is there a way to test the loss of GPS provider on Android? (onProviderDisabled())

Tags: android, eclipse, gps, ddms

I'd like to test my LocationListener() fully on the emulator, to see if it works correctly in all circumstances. Is there a way to test onProviderDisabled() and onProviderEnabled() using the emulator?

```
    location_listener = new LocationListener(){

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // Update application based on new location 
            updateLocation(location); 
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // Update application if provider disabled
            setContentView(R.layout.lostgps);
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // Update application if provider enabled 
            setContentView(R.layout.game); 
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            // Update application if provider hardware status changed 
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [LocationManager.setTestProviderEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#setTestProviderEnabled%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) and [LocationManager.setTestProviderStatus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#setTestProviderStatus%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20long%29) to test the listener.